# How to get webservice client information on webservice hosting machine

Tags: java, web-services, netbeans-8

I have deployed some webservices on a machine A using Netbeans and I am trying to log the time and IP information when someone tries to access them. 
I tried the following code snippet.

```
HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) 
mc.get(MessageContext.SERVLET_REQUEST);
System.out.println("Client IP = " + req.getRemoteAddr());
System.out.println(req.getRemoteHost());
```

But the output displays the IP of machine A.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Although this is similar to what you've tried, it worked for me for a SOAP request.

```
@Resource
WebServiceContext wsContext;

HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)wsContext.getMessageContext().get(SOAPMessageContext.SERVLET_REQUEST);

String remoteIp = request.getRemoteAddr();
String remoteUser = request.getRemoteUser();
String remoteHost = request.getRemoteHost();
```

Comment: @MohsinJavaid - not trying to be funny here - are you *sure* it's not machine A calling your web service?

Comment: nop. I am sending request from my laptop (Machine B). The webservices are hosted on a server machine (Machine A).

Comment: I assume they have different IPs. What about trying a machine that's definitely not on your network - maybe a public one in a library etc